# No quiere arrancar apachen en el Xampp

Tags: php, sql, postgresql, apache, xampp

mi problema es que apache no quiere correr en xampp ya probe con combiar el puerto 80 por 8080 y otros como 8081,8082,81,79 pero no me corrre tambie trate al cambiar el puerto del archivo apache,httt,sss.conf que era 443 y lo mis mo no funciono me gustaria saber si tiene alguna solucion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Ingresa al archivo "Apache (httpd.conf)", busca estas líneas de código y coloca los puertos:

**#Listen 15.50.80.90:8080

Listen 8080**

**ServerName localhost:8080**

Guardas los cambios.

Después da clic en el primer botón que dice **"Config"** *tiene una llave*, luego das clic en **Services and Port settings** y en la pestaña donde dice **"Apache"** coloca el mismo puerto (s) que pusiste en las anteriores líneas de código, guarda los cambios y pruebas.